# Spring Batch read/write count does not match with the actual number of records executed

Tags: spring-batch

Am using Quartz scheduler and running spring batches.. The number of threads is 5 and the commit interval is 20.. 
If there are 100 records to be picked up by the batch and when it is running i happen to stop the batch execution in between .. the read count and the write count in the BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION table is say 'n' .. But the BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT has the record count as 'n'+/-, but not the same.. There is usually a mismatch between these tables.. 
It is also observed that sometimes there are more number of records processed and committed but the number of count in these tables is much lesser.. 
Please can anyone explain..

Answer (score 0):

While we'd need to see your configuration with the actual `ItemReader`s you're using to give exact answers, from a general perspective, those two tables serve two different purposes which is why the numbers vary.

`BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION` stores metadata for the step in general.  The read count there will be the actual number of items read during a given step execution.

`BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT` stores state information directly from the `ItemReader`, etc.  Because of this, the value for restart may be different than the number that was actually read (when factoring for things like skips, commit boundaries, etc).